# Submitting an SGE job to PBS/Torque

Tags: converters, sungridengine, pbs, qsub, torque

Hi I am setting up a software pipeline (an extensive bioinformatic annotation tool) that was originally written to submit SGE jobs but I am on a PBS/Torque cluster. Any ideas about a way to convert these scripts from SGE to PBS? Or a piece of software available that can submit SGE jobs to PBS?

Thanks, Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search on the web found:

http://wiki.ibest.uidaho.edu/help/Tutorials/SGE_PBS_Converting.html

Creating a script that does replacement using the table from the above link would be simple, if not somewhat tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful side-by-side comparison of Torque and SGE commands: 
https://kb.iu.edu/d/avgl.

I don't know of any tool that would convert the scripts automatically, since in some aspects the two systems can be quite different (e.g. they handle parallel environments differently, etc.).